# How can I implement Chua diode in LT-Spice

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, resistors, diodes, inductor

I am simulating Chua circuit but it is not work properly. please help me to find out the region. In this schematic I am using simple diode instead of DIN 914. Actually I don't find this model so instead of this I am using simple Diode.  [image]

Comment: 1N914 is a standard diode in LTspice, afaik. If not this is a model: .model 1N914 D(Is=2.52n Rs=.568 N=1.752 Cjo=4p M=.4 tt=20n Iave=200m Vpk=75 mfg=OnSemi type=silicon) Can you be a bit more specific as to your problem and question? You are expecting oscillation?

Comment: DIN 914 is a German standard for the dimensions of set screws. You're probably thinking of the 1N914 (note that's 1N, not IN) diode, which used to be a very common small-signal diode, but is now basically obsolete and replaced by the 1N4148, which has near-identical characteristics.

Comment: yes sir I need oscillations in the circuit but after using diode 1N914 not shown proper oscillations.

Comment: I also check this foe the diode 1N914 from this also not get proper results

Comment: @UshaKumari I don't think Hearth is a "sir". That's not really a problem, what I want to say is: no need to be so formal :) it's usually nicer to stay a bit gender-generic.

Answer (score 1):

No diode needed (?).

Here is the behavior of one type of Chua's circuit.

[image]

Comment: Sir instead of LMC6482A_NS can I use any other OP-AMP

Comment: Yes. You can use other opamp. I think they will work, but not tested.